# Can't replace the value in HashMap even that the key and value exist and the map initialized (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, oop, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I'm working on a project of a cinema , and I have a HashMap `Map<String , String> movieTicketsMap = new HashMap<>();` as a variable in one of the classes which called Movie , and in Movie constructor I initialize the hash map and then put a multiple keys and values in it , then when I'm trying to replace some value with another it returns null and throws a NullPoinerException and don't replace the value !
I made sure that the key exist and has an value but it still throws the exception anyway !
So, I can't replace the value in HashMap even that the key and value exist and the map initialized !
here is a stashes of my code:
Movie Class:

```
private String movieTitle;
    private Cinema movieCinema;
    private Type movieType; //Enum
    private ArrayList<Date> movieShowTimesList; //FK
    private int movieRating;
    private ImageIcon movieImage;
    private ArrayList<Ticket> movieTicketsList;
    private Map<String , String> movieTicketsMap;
    private int movieID; //PK
    private static int movieIDInitializer;
    private static ArrayList<Movie> movieList;

public Movie(String movieTitle, Type movieType, int movieRating, String movieImagePath, Cinema movieCinema
                ,int year , int month , int day) {
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
        this.movieType = movieType;
        this.movieRating = movieRating;
        this.movieImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(movieImagePath));
        this.movieCinema = movieCinema;
        movieID = movieIDInitializer;
        movieIDInitializer++;
        go.saveInitializer("Movie");

        movieShowTimesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++ ) {
            movieShowTimesList.add(movieCinema.getShowTime(year , month , day , i , this.movieID));
        }

        movieTicketsList = new ArrayList<>();
        movieCinema.makeSeatsTicketedTo(this);
        
        movieTicketsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < movieTicketsList.size() ; i++){
            String showtimeKey = go.createShowtimeID(this.movieTicketsList.get(i).getTicketShowTime());
            movieTicketsMap.put(showtimeKey+movieTicketsList.get(i).getTicketSeat().getSeatID() , movieTicketsList.get(i).getTicketID());
        }
        
        go.save("Movie" , this , this.movieID);
        movieList.add(this);
        go.save("Movie" , movieList);
    }

    


    public void replaceValueInMovieTicetsMap(String key , String newValue){
        this.movieTicketsMap.replace(key, newValue);
    }
```

where I call the method `replaceValueInMovieTicetsMap(key , value);` in class Ticket:
in method `setTicketSeatStatus(booked);`

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable{
private Cinema ticketCinema; //FK
    private Seat ticketSeat; //FK
    private Date ticketShowTime; //FK
    private Movie ticketMovie; //FK
    private String ticketID; //PK
    private static ArrayList<Ticket> ticketList;

    public Ticket(Cinema ticketCinema, Seat ticketSeat, Date ticketShowTime, Movie ticketMovie) {
        this.ticketCinema = ticketCinema;
        this.ticketSeat = ticketSeat;
        this.ticketShowTime = ticketShowTime;
        this.ticketMovie = ticketMovie;
        generateTicketID();

        go.save("Ticket" , this , this.ticketID);
        ticketList.add(this);
        go.save("Ticket" , ticketList);
    }

    public void generateTicketID() {
        byte isBookedByte = 0;
        if(ticketSeat.isBooked()){
            isBookedByte = 1;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String oldTicketID = ticketID;
        ticketID = String.valueOf( ticketCinema.getCinemaID() ) + String.valueOf(ticketShowTime.getYear()+1900) + String.valueOf((ticketShowTime.getMonth()+1) + s.format(ticketShowTime) + String.valueOf(ticketShowTime.getHours()) + ticketShowTime.getMinutes()) + ticketSeat.getSeatID() + isBookedByte;
        go.rename("Ticket" , oldTicketID , ticketID);
        go.save("Ticket" , ticketList);
    }

    public void setTicketSeatStatus(boolean booked){
        this.ticketSeat.setBooked(booked);
        generateTicketID();
        String showtimekey = go.createShowtimeID(this.ticketShowTime);
/*Error Here->*/ this.ticketMovie.replaceValueInMovieTicetsMap(( showtimekey+this.ticketSeat.getSeatID()) ,this.ticketID);
        go.save("Ticket" , this , this.ticketID);
    }
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

I tried to call the method `map.replace(key , value);` directly but it doesn't work.
I thخught that the key I'm passing is wrong and found out that it's right !
I know thats hopless but also I tried to surround the sentence with try and catch so the Exception is no longer appears but the value didn't replaced ofcourse.

this is the exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainPackage.Movie.replaceValueInMovieTicetsMap(Movie.java:59)
    at MainPackage.Ticket.setTicketSeatStatus(Ticket.java:55)
    at Action.Ticketing.bookTicket(Ticketing.java:30)
    at Interfaces.booked_ticket_form.lblBookMouseClicked(booked_ticket_form.java:1640)
    at Interfaces.booked_ticket_form.access$5300(booked_ticket_form.java:23)
    at Interfaces.booked_ticket_form$52.mouseClicked(booked_ticket_form.java:597)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The Variable which is being null is : `movieTicketsMap<String , String>` in class `Movie` which used in method `setTicketSeatStatus(booked)` in class `Ticket`

Why I'm strongly feel that it shouldn't be null: it's because I made sure that the entered key is exist, how is that? because of this:
in my project every movie object has a variable which is `movieTicketsMap` and in this hash map the keys are the showtime of an ticket + the seat ID of it and the values are the tickets IDs, and this map has that information about all the tickets I have for that movie.
So, whem I'm trying to replace a value in the map , I'm Passing the showtime + the seat ID in the ticket ... so I don't know why it's returning null!!
is There anything I did wrong or what the reason of the null value?

Comment: Please 1) show the exception stack trace, 2) indicate which line throws the exception 3) indicate which variable is null, and 4) tell why you strongly feel that it shouldn't be null. There are all steps needed to help fully understand and debug the exception.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for remembering me ... I clarified the situation know , can you think about any idea might help , and thank you already

Comment: movieTicketsMap may not in fact be null. I'm wondering if it is one of the two Strings that you're passing into the method may be null. More importantly -- what does your debugger tell you when you step through the program, checking what is null just before that line is called?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't know if I used the debugger correctly but the result I had:
there is nothing null the debugger says , every thing has an value

Comment: Then you're probably not using it correctly. Have you placed break point *just* before the line that throws the exception? If not, do so, and inspect all the key variables at that time.

Comment: Otherwise, if you need more help here, you'd probably need to create a new program for us to test, a [mre], but that would require a lot of work on your part. Keep working with the debugger as I bet that that is your best option.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok I reach it , the debugger says that the movieTicketsMap it self is null !! 
although I initialized it in the Movie constructor!

Comment: .... and there is no way for us to know why this is so without your creating and posting a [mre]. Check that Movie doesn't have more than one constructor. Trace back to where you call the methods that trips the error.... more debugging or a MRE. your choice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks really really much I did configure what the wrong!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks really really much I did configure what the wrong!
it was that I'm passing the movie object to the Ticket constructor before I fill the movieTicketsMap in movie constructor , I thought that the movie object must be passed by reference so when I fill the map in the movie constructor the movie in the Ticket object must change as well but for some reason the movie object kept the movieTicketsMap without changing the null value of it ....
So, I just moved the line of the map initializing up a few lines to be before the tickets initializing method line,

Comment: ........ and I moved the code
```
String showtimeKey = go.createShowtimeID(this.movieTicketsList.get(i).getTicketShowTime());
            movieTicketsMap.put(showtimeKey+movieTicketsList.get(i).getTicketSeat().getSeatID() , movieTicketsList.get(i).getTicketID());
```
inside the method `makeSeatsTicketedto(Movie movie)` in class Cinema

Comment: I'm so glad that you've figured out the problem.  But also, do you also see how it is very likely that none of us could have figured out the problem based on the code that you've posted? We have no access to the `go` variable's code for instance. Please, again, look at the [mre] link for future reference should you decide to ask a future question.